# No rule to make target '/usr/lib/clucene_dll.o', needed by 'CLuceneWrap.so'

Tags: perl, ubuntu, cpan

I am installing the [`CLucene`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CLucene) module using this command

```
cpan>install CLucene
```

when I install the following error occurs

```
Reading '/root/.local/share/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Thu, 07 Apr 2016 10:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'CLucene'
Checksum for /root/.local/share/.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PE/PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.local/share/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring P/PE/PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for CLucene
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for P/PE/PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00.tar.gz
make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/clucene_dll.o', needed by   'CLuceneWrap.so'.  Stop.
PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00.tar.gz                 : make NO
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which platform? Windows? If yes, which perl? StrawberryPerl? ActivePerl?

Comment: @dotmen: The paths are Linux paths

Comment: I am using ubuntu 15.04 perl version is 5.20

Comment: cross post from http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1159802

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [`README` file](https://metacpan.org/source/PEDWARDS/CLucene-1.00/README) in the distribution you will see that it says this

> This module requires these other modules and libraries:
>
> CLucene engine from the RPM available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene.
>       Carp.
>       File::Path.

The file `/usr/lib/clucene_dll.o` is almost certainly a part of the CLucene engine installation, so it looks like you still need to do that

If you think you have installed the engine then you need to investigate why its components aren't where the Perl installer is looking

The URL provided is actually a dead link and you should look at [**clucene.sourceforge.net**](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/) instead

Comment: `The URL provided is actually a dead link` works fine from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/clucene